# Can you use acrylic gesso for oil paint?

Tags: oil-paint, preparation

I recently bought a bottle for acrylic gesso. I had enough practice with acrylics, now I want to switch to oil paint. Will the acrylic gesso work if I use it to prepare a board or a piece of wood?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes, you can.

Longer answer is that there is a some uncertainty around using an acrylic gesso for oil, but it's clear that doing it right makes a real difference here. If you take the appropriate steps and properly prepare for oils, it should be fine.

[The Artist's Network](http://www.artistsnetwork.com/medium/acrylic/can-acrylic-gesso-support-your-oils) has a really good article on the topic and the essentials really boil down getting the right level of tooth in the final result so as to maximize the ability of the oil to adhere to the surface.